# Laravel (on Linux, EC2) routes won't work

Tags: linux, laravel, amazon-ec2, routes

I have Laravel finally configured (for the most part) on my linux EC2 instance, but right now I can't get to any routes past my home page. All I get back is that *.net/people is not on the server. Anybody have any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using apache, check if your .htaccess is working. For example add 'deny from all' line at the beginning of file. If not - check your httpd.conf. Find `<Directory />` block, if there is `AllowOverride None` line, change it to `AllowOverride All` and restart your apache.